# EF Core 2.2 - how to create SqlExpression with AT TIME ZONE SQL fragment

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to map method to custom SQL, which is

```
CONVERT(datetime, 
        SWITCHOFFSET(GETUTCDATE(), DATEPART(TZOFFSET, GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time')))
```

So I added `HasDbFunction` in my `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.GetDateTime)))
        .HasTranslation(e =>
            {
                var GETUTCDATE = new SqlFunctionExpression("GETUTCDATE", typeof(DateTime));
                
                var TZOFFSET = new SqlFragmentExpression("TZOFFSET");
                var ATTIMEZONE = new SqlFragmentExpression(" AT TIME ZONE ");
                var GreenwichStandardTime = new Expression("Greenwich Standard Time"); // expression with constant?
                var EXPRESSION = new Expression(GETUTCDATE, ATTIMEZONE, GreenwichStandardTime); // expression with combine multiple exprssions?
                var DATEPART = new SqlFunctionExpression("DATEPART", typeof(int), new[] { TZOFFSET , EXPRESSION  });  // cannot create

                var SWITCHOFFSET = new SqlFunctionExpression("SWITCHOFFSET", typeof(DateTimeOffset), new[] { GETUTCDATE, DATEPART });

                var DATETIME = new SqlFragmentExpression("DATETIME");
                
                new SqlFunctionExpression("CONVERT", typeof(DateTime), new[] { DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET });
            });
```

My question is how can I create GreenwichStandardTime and EXPRESSION?

Comment: What's wrong with another `SqlFragmentExpression`? In fact, given that the whole thing is just one big expression, why not just create it as a single `SqlFragmentExpression`

Comment: @Charlieface I create it as SqlFragmentExpression, and it is working. Can I ask you if I want to replace "Greenwich Standard Time" with other wording from Method parameter, look like it cannot translate it to string value.

Comment: `DbContext.GetDateTime` needs a `string` parameter, then you can construct the expression using `args[0]`. See also https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2022/03/custom-ef-core-function-to-use-transact.html

Answer (score 0):

From @Charlieface we can create expression from SqlFragmentExpression

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.GetDateTime)))
    .HasTranslation(e =>
        {
            var DATETIME = new SqlFragmentExpression("DATETIME");
            var SWITCHOFFSET= new SqlFragmentExpression(
                                 $@" SWITCHOFFSET(GETUTCDATE(), 
                                 DATEPART(TZOFFSET, GETUTCDATE() 
                                 AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time')) ");

            return new SqlFunctionExpression("CONVERT", typeof(string), new[] { DATETIME , SWITCHOFFSET });
        });
```

in case I want to replace 'Greenwich Standard Time' with function parameter as @Charlieface use

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.GetDateTime), new[] {typeof(string)}))
    .HasTranslation(e =>
        {
            var constantExpression = e.First() as ConstantExpression;
            var DATETIME = new SqlFragmentExpression("DATETIME");
            var SWITCHOFFSET= new SqlFragmentExpression(
                                 $@" SWITCHOFFSET(GETUTCDATE(), 
                                 DATEPART(TZOFFSET, GETUTCDATE() 
                                 AT TIME ZONE '{constantExpression.Value}')) ");

            return new SqlFunctionExpression("CONVERT", typeof(string), new[] { DATETIME , SWITCHOFFSET });
        });


public DateTime GetDateTime([NotParameterized] string timeZone){
  throw new NotImplementedException()
}
```

[NotParameterized] will not convert it to parameter on expression